# Retrieve data from database to textbox wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to fetch data from PHP MyAdmin database to WordPress website page. Since I am new to WordPress I am not too sure which method I have to follow. I tried to edit the source code of the page by adding the new PHP code inside PHP tags. But it did not work. And I found a file named 'functions.php' in the local directory where my project located. Is that the file I need to use this code? I've already written the code and I just need to know where to use it.

```
<?php
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name"); // Query to fetch data from database table and storing in $results
if(!empty($results))                        // Checking if $results have some values or not
{    
    echo "<table width='100%' border='0'>"; // Adding <table> and <tbody> tag outside foreach loop so that it wont create again and again
    echo "<tbody>";      
    foreach($results as $row){   
    $userip = $row->user_ip;               //putting the user_ip field value in variable to use it later in update query
    echo "<tr>";                           // Adding rows of table inside foreach loop
    echo "<th>ID</th>" . "<td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<td colspan='2'><hr size='1'></td>";
    echo "<tr>";        
    echo "<th>User IP</th>" . "<td>" . $row->user_ip . "</td>";   //fetching data from user_ip field
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<td colspan='2'><hr size='1'></td>";
    echo "<tr>";        
    echo "<th>Post ID</th>" . "<td>" . $row->post_id . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<td colspan='2'><hr size='1'></td>";
    echo "<tr>";        
    echo "<th>Time</th>" . "<td>" . $row->time . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<td colspan='2'><hr size='1'></td>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>"; 

}
?>
```

Comment: Wrap this code into a function that you can place into your functions.php file then call it from a page template.

Comment: You can also add code to your template file for result listing.